# Check if macro is odd in c++

Tags: c++, directive

I have a macro that is just a constant value:

```
#define THREAD_AT_DEPTH 13
```

I want to throw an error at compile time if I set that value to something even.

```
#if (THREAD_AT_DEPTH % 2) == 0
#error THREAD_AT_DEPTH must be odd
#endif
```

Unfortunately, `THREAD_AT_DEPTH % 2` isn't being evaluated at compile-time, and `#error` is always in effect.  If I change `THREAD_AT_DEPTH` to `13`, my `#if` directive works as intended.

Is there a way to make defined macros evaluate correctly?

**EDIT**: this question didn't match my code.  The above works as expected.  I hadn't realized that the code that wasn't working was using

```
const int THREAD_AT_DEPTH = 13;

//...

#if (THREAD_AT_DEPTH % 2) == 1
//...
```

When I changed it to

```
#define THREAD_AT_DEPTH 13
```

my `#if` directive worked as expected.

Now, I'm not sure if I should leave this question here or delete it.

Comment: Can you use `constexpr` and `static_assert` instead? Requires C++11, I believe.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Work as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69f2985d1399250e)

Comment: I just realized that the code I have and the code I wrote here are different.  I was using `const int THREAD_AT_DEPTH = 13` and then my `#if` directive.  If I change it to `#define THREAD_AT_DEPTH 13`, it works as intended.

Comment: Should I delete the OP or leave it with the edit explaining that the OP was wrong?

Comment: You won't be able to delete it. The person who answered bellow doesn't deserve to lose their upvotes because of your mistake. So the system simply won't let you.

Comment: Not to mention that the answer still applies. `static_assert` works fine with the given `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 you can use [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) for this.